# can not resolve method add for Fragment Transaction - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, fragmentmanager, fragmenttransaction

I was just upgrading old android project and stuck at below code :

```
 FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 transaction.add(R.id.instructional_tutorial_video_youtube_view, youTubePlayerFragment).commit();
 return view;
```

Here, It giving me a compile time error : **can not resolve method add(int, com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment)**

The Xml file named R.id.**instructional_tutorial_video_youtube_view** is as below :

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.brian.skyazul.fragment.InstructionTutorialVideoViewFragment">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/video_topbar"
        layout="@layout/topbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/instructional_tutorial_video_youtube_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/video_topbar"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

What might causing the issue? Or Is there any alternative to resolve this? thanks.

Comment: Where you're getting this instance youTubePlayerFragment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using this, I just used :

```
implementation 'com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer:core:11.0.1'

<com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.views.YouTubePlayerView
    android:id="@+id/instructional_tutorial_video_youtube_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/video_topbar"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

and inside Java :

```
 YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = findViewById(R.id.instructional_tutorial_video_youtube_view);
    youTubePlayerView.addYouTubePlayerListener(new AbstractYouTubePlayerListener() {
        @Override
        public void onReady(@NonNull YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer) {
            String videoId = youtubeVideoURL;//"S0Q4gqBUs7c";
            youTubePlayer.loadVideo(videoId, 0);
        }
    });
```

and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

fragment tag instead of YoutubePlayerView tag

```
<fragment
android:id="@+id/youtubeFragment"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment">
```

**I haven't used before, I hope playerview it's in fragment itself.**

In your fragment class

```
val youtubeFragment =
        childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.youtubeFragment) as YouTubePlayerFragment
    youtubeFragment.initialize("YOUR API KEY",
        object : OnInitializedListener() {
            fun onInitializationSuccess(
                provider: YouTubePlayer.Provider?,
                youTubePlayer: YouTubePlayer, b: Boolean
            ) {
                // do any work here to cue video, play video, etc.    
                youTubePlayer.cueVideo("")
            }

            fun onInitializationFailure(
                provider: YouTubePlayer.Provider?,
                youTubeInitializationResult: YouTubeInitializationResult?
            ) {
            }
        })
```